# Beginner Rails Deployment to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

This is my first rails deployment to Heroku. I've been watching and reading countless resources and still can't figure out why I'm getting so many errors. I've transitioned over to postgresql on deployment, added ruby version into gemfile, setup puma and a procfile. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
heroku logs
2015-07-03T20:10:25.239238+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by myemail@address.com
2015-07-03T20:10:25.322364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-03T20:10:29.668690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657586+00:00 app[web.1]: config/puma.rb:66:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `path_to_key' for #<Puma::DSL:0x007f3dbbc6d798> (NameError)
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657616+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657618+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `_load_from'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657620+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:9:in `block in load'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `tap'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657622+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657624+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:35:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657625+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:545:in `parse_options'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657626+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:190:in `run'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657627+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657632+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-07-03T20:10:31.657629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:10:32.427366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-03T20:10:32.416181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-03T20:10:53.231676+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheltered-bastion-3907.herokuapp.com request_id=270e6357-61b1-4a76-be72-48ffaddca924 fwd="73.219.192.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-03T20:10:53.117888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-bastion-3907.herokuapp.com request_id=07da6d55-0f58-419e-b43c-bd5b2d6826af fwd="73.219.192.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-03T20:17:47.455257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-03T20:17:52.666069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638707+00:00 app[web.1]: config/puma.rb:66:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `path_to_key' for #<Puma::DSL:0x007fc6d540e7c0> (NameError)
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638733+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638735+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `_load_from'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638737+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:9:in `block in load'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638738+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `tap'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638741+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:35:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638742+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:545:in `parse_options'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638740+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638743+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:190:in `run'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638745+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638748+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:17:54.638750+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-07-03T20:17:55.418705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-03T20:17:55.419971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-03T20:17:55.402960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-03T20:18:00.150833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318326+00:00 app[web.1]: config/puma.rb:66:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `path_to_key' for #<Puma::DSL:0x007f3df1b321e0> (NameError)
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `_load_from'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318356+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `tap'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318355+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:9:in `block in load'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318359+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:545:in `parse_options'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318358+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:35:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318360+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:190:in `run'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318361+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318362+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:18:02.318364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-07-03T20:18:03.109652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-03T20:18:03.087281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-03T20:18:05.096319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-bastion-3907.herokuapp.com request_id=0ad389e3-a02f-43f2-a29c-ad4e8aeb2106 fwd="73.219.192.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-03T20:18:05.333898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheltered-bastion-3907.herokuapp.com request_id=201736a7-5254-4467-bb0c-fc49c7ca8e61 fwd="73.219.192.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-03T20:21:39.079385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-03T20:21:51.485731+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by myemail@address.com
2015-07-03T20:21:55.526689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-07-03T20:21:57.017844+00:00 heroku[run.6543]: Awaiting client
2015-07-03T20:21:57.051627+00:00 heroku[run.6543]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-07-03T20:21:57.186947+00:00 heroku[run.6543]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471779+00:00 app[web.1]: config/puma.rb:66:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `path_to_key' for #<Puma::DSL:0x007fe598fddab0> (NameError)
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471809+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `_load_from'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:9:in `block in load'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `tap'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471813+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471814+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:35:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:545:in `parse_options'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471817+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:190:in `run'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471818+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471828+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:21:57.471830+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-07-03T20:21:58.226945+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-03T20:21:58.240543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-03T20:22:15.185831+00:00 heroku[run.6543]: State changed from up to complete
2015-07-03T20:22:15.170261+00:00 heroku[run.6543]: Process exited with status 0
2015-07-03T20:22:33.180767+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by myemail@address.com
2015-07-03T20:22:39.525530+00:00 heroku[run.2044]: Awaiting client
2015-07-03T20:22:39.555404+00:00 heroku[run.2044]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-07-03T20:22:39.843264+00:00 heroku[run.2044]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-03T20:22:47.821258+00:00 heroku[run.2044]: State changed from up to complete
2015-07-03T20:22:47.804773+00:00 heroku[run.2044]: Process exited with status 0
2015-07-03T20:24:08.475083+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9ef9d59 by myemail@address.com
2015-07-03T20:24:08.475083+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by myemail@address.com
2015-07-03T20:24:08.524035+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-03T20:24:08.524042+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-07-03T20:24:08.595914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-03T20:24:17.032551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-07-03T20:24:19.244953+00:00 app[web.1]: config/puma.rb:66:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `path_to_key' for #<Puma::DSL:0x007efccd061870> (NameError)
2015-07-03T20:24:19.244976+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.244979+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:9:in `block in load'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.244978+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:20:in `_load_from'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.244981+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `tap'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245034+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/dsl.rb:8:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245036+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:35:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245037+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:545:in `parse_options'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245038+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:190:in `run'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245041+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-07-03T20:24:19.245042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-07-03T20:24:20.019209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-03T20:24:20.009361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you created a `config/puma.rb` file along with your `Procfile`? If not, create it by adding this to your `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Then, create a file named `config/puma.rb` and set it up like so:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

See if that helps. More information can be found in the docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server). You may have already considered this, but it's an initial action to narrow your problem down a bit.

Comment: the plain text file named `Procfile` should be placed in the root rails directory correct?

Comment: You're welcome! If this helped, an upvote and answer acceptance would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I used the config/puma.rb file from the accepted answer of this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946153/how-do-i-use-pumas-configuration-file). Is there a certain reason his puma.rb wouldn't work with mine or just something I'll have to research by searching through the docs?

Comment: Yes, because he has custom relative paths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82338/discussion-between-inthenameofmusik-and-collin-graves).